# Entities missing from discriminator maps

Tags: php, symfony, centos, doctrine, vagrant

I am using `Symfony 3.3.15` with `Doctrine 2.5.14` setup on a Vagrant virtual machine running `CentOS 7`, `php 7.0.25` and `mariaDB 5.5.56`.

I have several sets of entities setup with single table inheritance. I'm letting Doctrine build the discriminator maps for me. For some reason Doctrine doesn't seem to be adding all the related entities to the discriminator maps. This is occurring with several groups of entities. eg:

I have one table mapped with 10 entities, but when I get the discriminator map with `$this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getClassMetadata(ParentEntity::class)` it only has 8 entries in the `discriminatorMap` array. When trying to load a page I get an error like this:

> Entity 'ChildEntity' has to be part of the discriminator map of 'ParentEntity' to be properly mapped in the inheritance hierarchy. Alternatively you can make 'ChildEntity' an abstract class to avoid this exception from occurring.

This is only occurring on my development machine. I have the code running in production (CentOS 7 on AWS) without issue.

I thought this might be a cache issue [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32766253/doctrine-discriminator-map-not-updating) but I've cleared the Symfony cache (and deleted and recreated it) and I've also cleared the Doctrine cache with `console doctrine:cache:clear-metadata` but nothing changes. I also tried setting the permissions on my whole project to `0777` but still no luck.

Does anyone know why I'm getting these errors and how I can fix them?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the exact problem was, but upgrading to the latest versions of Vagrant (2.0.2) and VirtualBox (5.2.6) fix this.